# Discovering vendor-specific bluetooth devices only

Tags: android, bluetooth

Need to discover or search for `Bluetooth` devices of certain "vendor-specific" devices.

"vendor-specific" means all devices will have similar starting bits in their "MAC" address

For example, I want to search only for devices whose MAC address starts with `12:34:56:`

It should search only for specific series of `MAC` addresses and list them.

Answer (score 4):

Perform a full discovery, then filter using [`BluetoothDevice.getAddress()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getAddress%28%29)

```
// Define Vendor ID Prefix
public static final String VENDOR_ID = "12:34:56:"

// First, do a full discovery...
BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().startDiscovery()

//...

// Then, for each device returned from discovery...

if ( device.getAddress().startsWith(VENDOR_ID) ) {
  // Do Something
}
```

Comment: this may be one way thanks.. **can there be any way to extend the BroadcastReceiver to search only specific devices??**

Comment: @Jay3545 As far as I know, there is no publicly documented way to do this. What is the problem with filtering a list of all devices? If speed is the problem, you could periodically perform discovery in the background, and maintain a list of devices filtered by vendor ID. Then, when your user "searches" for devices, just display the latest version of this list.

Answer (score 2):

My Explanation will be based on the BluetoothChat example from the Android SDK, hopefully this is ok, otherwise I would need to write a lot more. If you haven't seen the BluetoothChat example, go take a look, it's really nice!

If you want to use a device where you don't know the complete adress, you'll have to do a complete discovery with `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()` and search the received addresses for the ones you want to.

If you know the complete address of the device you want to connect to you can directly connect to this device with `BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address)`